# Get text from previous activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to get the data from previous `Activity` to a `Fragment`. I am able to get the data without `Fragment` but, when I put the code inside `Fragment`, it doesn't work. My Fragment is inside description class. Here is my code:

This is how I am sending data from previous `Activity`:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
String text = textView.getText().toString();
    if(text.equals("ADA")) {
        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), description.class);
        intent.putExtra("ADA", text);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
```

This is how I am getting it inside `Fragment`:

```
public static class DummyFragment extends Fragment {
    int color;
    TextView mTextview;

    public DummyFragment() {
    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public DummyFragment(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment, container, false);

        final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_bg);
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_scrollableview);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mTextview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mTextview.setText(getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("ADA"));

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/dummyfrag_bg"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/bg_light">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/dummyfrag_scrollableview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you calling `startActivity(intent)` in the fragment? If you want to pass data to a Fragment, use a `Bundle`, not `Intent`

Comment: So, you mean to say Intent will not work in fragment?

Comment: It might but `getActivity().getIntent()` should ideally be `getArguments()` (where the later is a Bundle, not Intent)

Comment: Check ρяσѕρєя K answer [enter link description here][1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Comment: I have updated the question. My Fragment is in another class named description.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
String text = textView.getText().toString();
if(text.equals("ADA")) {
   DummyFragment fragment = new DummyFragment();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("ADA",text);
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);
   getSupportFragmentManager()
         .beginTransaction()
         .replace(fragment,R.id.layout)
         .addTobackStack(null)
         .commit();
}
```

then in your fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment, container, false);
        String text = getArguments().getString("ADA");

}
```

EDIT

Explaination

1) fragmentTransaction.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)

Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

2) fragmentTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)

Add a fragment to the activity state. This fragment may optionally also have its view (if Fragment.onCreateView returns non-null) into a container view of the activity.

Comment: What is `.replace(fragment,R.id.layout)` ?

Comment: find how to create fragment here https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences to store the text. Do this in the Activity before loading fragment

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TextHolder", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("ADA", textView.getText().toString()).apply();
```

Inside the Fragment get the text from SharedPreferences like this

```
String textHolder = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("TextHolder", 0).getString("ADA", "");
```

Now set the textHolder String to the TextView of your choice inside the Fragment